# How to fetch the path's value for the incoming URL in Jersey?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jersey

Let's say that I setup the following Jersey resource:

```
@Path("/blah")
public class BlahResource {
    @GET
    @Path("/")
    public String printRelativeUrlPath()
    {
        System.out.println("I want to print the relative path that lands us in this method");
        System.out.println("For Ex: /do/1/then/2");
        System.out.println("For Ex: /wait/3/then/4");
        System.out.println("For Ex: /done/5/done/6");
    }
}
```

I want to be able to print out the relative url paths that reach this method, for ex:

- GET `http://somehost/blah/do/1/then/2` should print `/do/1/then/2`
- GET `http://somehost/blah/wait/3/then/4` should print `/wait/3/then/4`
- GET `http://somehost/blah/done/5/done/6` should print `/done/5/done/6`

How do I get at this info when I'm using Jersey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use @Context HttpServletRequest request to obtain HttpServletRequest as mentioned here 
http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Access-to-Servlet-Request-td5538642.html

And then use methods in HttpServletRequest to fetch the URL. Eg: method getPathTranslated()

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html

Comment: Ok this is going to sound dumb but I pressed the hot key for auto-organize on eclipse and given my current maven+jar+dependency setup ... it couldn't find an import for HttpServletRequest! I looked around some more and passing in `@Context UriInfo allUri` as an argument and then evaluating it as `System.out.println(allUri.getPath());` did the trick!